# Showing Vaaler polynomial is a good approximation to saw tooth function

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis, trigonometric-polynomials

Vaaler's polynomial is defined
$$
V_K(x) = \frac{1}{K+1}\sum_{k=1}^K\left(\frac{k}{K+1} - \frac12\right) \Delta_{K+1}\left(x - \frac{k}{K+1}\right) +
\frac{1}{2 \pi (K+1)}\sin 2 \pi (K+1) x - \frac{1}{2 \pi} \Delta_{K+1}(x) \sin 2 \pi x,
$$
where
$$
\Delta_K(x) = \sum_{-K}^K \left(1 - \frac{|k|}{K}\right)e(kx)
$$
is the Fejér kernel.
I am interested in seeing how one can show
$$
V_K(x) = s(x) + O\left(\min \left(1, \frac{1}{K^3 \lVert x\rVert^3}\right)\right). 
$$
Here $s(x)$ is the saw tooth function.
This equation is stated in Montgomery's "[Ten Lectures on the Interface Between Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis](https://doi.org/10.1090/cbms/084)" without further explanation. Any reference or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Could just be me, but I can't see the whole first display (last thing I can see is $-\frac{1}{2\pi}\Delta$).

Comment: Why not look at the original paper of Vaaler, "Some Extremal Functions in Fourier Analysis", Bull AMS, 12(2), April 1985, p 183-216, starting on p 206. You can find it at Project Euclid https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-12/issue-2/Some-extremal-functions-in-Fourier-analysis/bams/1183552525.full